# mysql_upgrade via queries

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqlupgrade

is there a way of detecting if I need to run mysql_upgrade without having access to the command-line so to the tool mysql_upgrade or mysql_check? I need a way that uses SQL-statements or something like that

Comment: Upgrade problem can have "a lot of" causes. Most of the times your (MySQL-)server will not start when problems are 'serious'.  So you could check if your server is running to detect problems ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `mysql_admin`.

BTW: mysql_upgrade is now deprecated. Below output is shown when yuo run it without parameters:

> The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by
> the upgrade client are now done by the server. To upgrade, please
> start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Repairing
> user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after
> upgrade. The upgrade process automatically starts on running a new
> MySQL binary with an older data directory. To avoid accidental
> upgrades, please use the --upgrade=NONE option with the MySQL binary.
> The option --upgrade=FORCE is also provided to run the server upgrade
> sequence on demand. It may be possible that the server upgrade fails
> due to a number of reasons. In that case, the upgrade sequence will
> run again during the next MySQL server start. If the server upgrade
> fails repeatedly, the server can be started with the --upgrade=MINIMAL
> option to start the server without executing the upgrade sequence,
> thus allowing users to manually rectify the problem.

Comment: Looks like deprecated starting from 8.0.16: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-16-mysql_upgrade-is-going-away/

What if I use older versions of mysql? Is there a way of detecting upgrade-problems, without having access to command-line tools like mysql_upgrade/mysql_admin and so. I need a solution that only uses sql-statements.